# Continuity of probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity

Sorry, I just wanted to know whether I understand this correct. Let $(x_n)$ be an increasing sequence such that $x_n \rightarrow a$, then we have for the probability measure on an arbitrary probability space with a random variable: 
$\lim_n P(X\le x_n) = P(X < a)$, although if this sequence would decrease from above against the same limit we would have: 
$\lim_n P(X\le x_n) = P(X \le a)$, right?

So, the last one is an actual right-side continuity. There appears to be a problem with this:
The CDF is called right-continuous, but I can only derive this result by using the continuity of measures. The problem is: Continuity of measures would assume that the sequence is monotone decreasing, which is not assumed in the context of right-side continuity, why is this no problem?

Comment: Yes. Is this your question?

Comment: I added something, maybe you could also help me with that=

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand where exactly you are seeing a problem.

Comment: I do not understand, the condition to check the "right-side continuity" inherently has a monotone-decreasing sequence of real numbers, or equivalently a monotone decreasing sequence of measurable subsets.

Comment: Okay, but not every sequence that comes from the right is monotone decreasing, one would have to look at the monotone decreasing subsequences first, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Exercise:* Let $H:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ denote a non-decreasing function. Show that $H$ is continuous from the right at $a$ if and only if $H(x_n)\to H(a)$ for at least one sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\geqslant a$ for every $n$ and $x_n\to a$ when $n\to\infty$, if and only if $H(a+1/n)\to H(a)$ when $n\to\infty$.

Recall that $H$ being continuous from the right at $a$ means that $H(x_n)\to H(a)$ for every sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\geqslant a$ for every $n$ and $x_n\to a$ when $n\to\infty$.